# Do I need to create 3 different types of WordPress Websites?

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, ip

I need to start working on a tours WordPress website and I got asked that if the user is local then it opens a page with some content for outgoing packages. However, if the user was from America for example, it opens Incoming and pilgrim packages. They also asked me to have 3 different languages for the website and depending on where the user is from, it opens the website with the visitor language accordingly and it also have the option to change language.

I was thinking the best way is to make 3 different WordPress websites with 2 sub domain and the domain is for a default language. However, it can have the same database so I don't have to re-insert the content.

Did I think right or is there another way that might save time and effort?

Thanks for help in advance :)

Comment: use something like [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) and save yourself the trouble of having to maintain three different installations.

Comment: Great but I want to offer some packages that are available for only incoming for instance: A visitor from America can see it but local can't.